# How to represent equivalence relation as a function in set theory?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

While writing a proof for below statement, I stuck at representing equivalence relation as a function.

Let $f : A → B $ be a function and let G be an equivalence relation in B.
Prove that the preimage of G i.e $f^\vee(G) = f^{-1}\circ G \circ f$.

I am thinking of representing equivalence relation as an ordered pair $G \times G$. But it is not a function.

Lets take B = { 1, 2, 4 } and let R be the relation representing even numbers. Now I will represent R as {(2,2), (4,4), (2,4), (4,2)}. R is not a function since in the order pairs (2,2) and (2,4), 2 is mapped to both 2 and 4. 
In the above case how can I represent R as a function.

Comment: The most obvious way to get an equivalence relation $G$ from a function $f$ is to take $G=\{(x,\,y)|f(x)=f(y)\}$. The most obvious way to get a function from an equivalence relation is to map $x$ to the set of $y$ satisfying $(x,\y)\in G$, i.e. $\{(z,\,y)\in G|z=x\}$.

Comment: @J.G., I didn't understand the way to get a function from an equivalence relation. To give more clarity on my question, I have edited it and added an example. Please help me prove the above statement.